# Citation Network Dataset

Tags: data-request, research

I am looking for an exhaustive Citation Network Dataset for research papers, ideally identified with DOIs.

So far I have found:

- [ACM-Citation-network and DBLP-Citation-network V8](https://aminer.org/citation)

[image]

which are quite small compared to the number of research papers (> 50 millions)

---

There is also the  [Patent citation network](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/cit-Patents.html), but it pertains to patents, and not research articles.

[image]

Comment: The American Physical Society provides access to citations in physics. The datasets are closed but free: https://journals.aps.org/datasets

Answer (score 3):

While it is certainly not exhaustive, the [Microsoft Academic Graph](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/microsoft-academic-graph/) is probably worth checking out.

They have a free public [API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/academic-knowledge-api) and the complete dataset is also [available for download](https://academicgraph.blob.core.windows.net/graph/index.html).

There appear to be roughly 127 million papers, 115 million author names, and 529 million references in the 2016/02/05 dataset dump.

DOI's are included in the dataset, but you will notice (particularly with older articles) that references and DOI data are incomplete.